# by using objects exclusively per thread (not shared between threads )is it needed to protect the member functions of that class?

Tags: c++, multithreading

if there was a case which each thread takes instances(objects) of a class exclusively(so that threads don't share these objects ) and works with their member functions (assume the class has no static function) is it needed to protect mutual exclusion for the member functions of that class?

Comment: If there is no shared memory, then there is no need for any type of memory barrier.

Comment: It's not memory specifically you have to worry about, it's resources in general. And if threads don'e share some resource, it's hard (for me at least) to see why you would have multiple threads.

Comment: You need not worry about static functions. Static objects in the class, member functions or any other function that are called using instances of the class matter. But static objects are not the only way of sharing resources.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to protect the members, if not public methods manipulate additionally said members.